# xbbg intraday bar requests raises error for fixed income

Tags: bloomberg

I am using this great package `xbbg`, essentially a wrapper around `blpapi` doing all the nasty connection issues for you and retrieving data in the form of pandas dfs.

In order to get intraday data, you have to first add the instrument in a .yml file. The examples were only with Index, Comdty, Equity and Curncy data, but I need fixed income data. I have added Corp in the assets.yml file in xbbg (running v0.7), wiriting the following:

```
Corp:
  - tickers: [IT0005425233]
    exch: MIL
```

However, I still get the error "Cannot fine exchange info".

MIL is correctly adde in the exchange.yml file:

```
MIL:
  tz: Europe/Rome
  allday: [800, 2200]
```

I also tried inserting the des ( `BTPS 1.7 09/01/51`)  instead of the ISIN in the .yml file, the issue is still there. Anybody here who had the same problem? If yes, how did you solve it?

I know there's a workaround where you supply the `ref=` kwarg but if you are trying to get data for different asset classes and different exchanges it gets messy, I'd like to get to the root of the issue from the .yml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most things, there is a short answer and a long answer.

The **short answer** is that the `xbbg.bdib()` function *does not handle bonds currently* (either with the `Corp` or `Govt` *yellow keys*). It only recognizes `Equity`, `Comdty`, `Curncy` and `Index`. The OP has done everything right, in terms of setting up `assets.yml` and `exch.yml`, but the code in `const.py` in the `xbbg` package has a hard-coded list of yellow keys and the ticker/exchange logic for each.

The **long answer** is to insert your own handling of `Govt` (or other yellow keys):

Add the MIL and HEL exchanges in `exch.yml` (as the OP is doing):

```
MIL:
  tz: Europe/Rome
  allday: [800, 2200]

HEL:
  tz: Europe/Helsinki
  allday: [730, 1300]
```

And in the `assets.yml` add the following section for `Govt`:

```
Govt:
  - isins: [IT]
    exch: MIL
  - isins: [FI]
    exch: HEL
```

Then in the calling code, create a `myBdib()` function, which forwards the call to the `bdib` function after determining the 'exchange' for the `Govt` yellow key:

```
from xbbg import blp,const
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

const.ASSET_INFO['Govt'] = ['isins']

def myBdib(ticker: str, dt, session='allday', typ='TRADE', **kwargs) -> pd.DataFrame:
    yellowKey = ticker.split()[-1]

    if yellowKey == 'Govt':
        entries = const.asset_config(yellowKey).set_index('isins')
        kwargs['ref']=entries['exch'][ticker[0:2]]

    return blp.bdib(ticker,dt,session,typ,**kwargs)

df = myBdib('IT0005425233 Govt',datetime(2023,1,26))
print(df)

df = myBdib('FI4000415153 Govt',datetime(2023,1,26))
print(df)

df = myBdib('EUR Curncy',datetime(2023,1,26))
print(df)
```

The `const.py` code in `xbbg` handles all the asset/exchange lookup. The line `const.ASSET_INFO['Govt'] = ['isins']` adds an entry to the default processing to tell the asset parser to look for the `isins` keyword for `Govt`. Here I am just using the first two characters of the ISIN to pick up the exchange, but you could use any approach. For example you could change the keyword `isins` to `tickers` in `assets.yml` and the code, and match on ticker (eg `BTPS`).

**NB**. There is a certain amount of caching going on. If you are having issues, try deleting all the files under the `..\xbbg\markets\cached` folder and running again.

Comment: good workaround, it will do for now. i might change the library itself and make a pull request on github, the caching structure is also weird as it doesn't let you handle different timeframes (if you ask 1h candles first and 1m candles right after, it returns 1h candles because it looks at the parquet files, which have no memory of the timeframe)

Comment: @user50473 Good plan. My other niggle with bdib() is that you can only get one day at a time. The underlying API lets you supply any start and end UTC datetimes. I'd probably add an `end_date` parameter. Then there is a bit of post-processing to filter out the rows in the dataframe that aren't in the session (and the session UTC times may change if you happened to span the DST change date). Also, I'd probably change the key from `isins` to `tickers` and do a check: if the ticker is 12 chars, then assume it's an ISIN and use the first two chars, otherwise search on the whole ticker (eg BTPS).